# The request timed out. The web server failed to respond within the specified time

Tags: asp.net, azure-web-app-service

I have hosted an ASP .NET web app in Azure App service. the function of web app is read the data from excel and match the data in Azure SQL database and post the data via API. The app runs good but the problem is that it wont run for longer time it throws an Error like

```
500 - The request timed out.
The web server failed to respond within the specified time.
```

I have also increased the execution time limit in Web.Config file.

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097152" executionTimeout="300000" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
</system.web>
```

Can any one please help here what I can do for this. Can I get minimum of 1 hour execution time?

Comment: you may have some connections that might be taking long to respond , also please check those and exceed timeout limit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## This problem occurs because of the browser. There is no problem with your code, no need to modify `httpRuntime`.

The browser has a default connection timeout, Chrome seems to be about 5 minutes, and the actual test shows `500-The request timed out.` in about 4 minutes.

**Test Code**

```
public int test()
{
    try
    {
        DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime dt2 = dt1.AddMinutes(10);
        while (DateTime.Now < dt2)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Tick("I am running");
        }
        return 1;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return -1;
        throw;
    }
}

public void Tick(object data)
{
    _logger.LogInformation(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "    " + data); 
}
```

**Phenomenon**

[image]

About 4 minutes or so, a 500 timeout error occurred in the browser, but I found that the backend was still running and the log was still recording.

[image]

## Suggestion

If the backend needs to process for an hour to return the result, it must return the result asynchronously. Synchronization is impossible, there is no reason to synchronize, even if the browser does not time out, you do not need to return synchronously, wasting resources.

To return the processing results in time, you can use WebSocket and Ajax polling, or signalr.

During the processing, the front end only needs to provide the Loading prompt, and then poll regularly to query the back-end processing results. If the processing is successful, the front-end prompt is updated successfully.