# EC2 configurations for timeout?

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-ec2, asp.net-core-webapi

Are there any EC2 configurations for timeout?

I have a dedicated EC2 server and there is a docker containerized .net 5.0 web API served on it. When I try to send long-running requests I get 504 Gateway Timeout after 90 seconds and I can see that requests end after 120 seconds on the logs in cloudwatch. Is there any EC2 configurations for timeout?

Comment: Can you provide more details? Are you accessing EC2 directly? Do you have any web servers installs on EC2?

Comment: We are accessing EC2 directly, no web servers like nginx/apache installed.

Comment: I think a better solution would be to submit a job and return 201 to indicate that it is already running, and then have an interface to query the running status of the job.

Comment: If you're thinking about real-time push, you can also consider using Signalr. In this way, jobs continue to run on the server side, and the http request will be returned immediately without being blocked, we can often see it when creating a virtual server in Azure Portal, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks @JasonPan. Your first suggestion "submit a job & return 201", to do this we'd have to create a job running system (redis/celery) and split long running tasks into chunks. Have I understood correctly?

Comment: Maybe `a job running system` is no needed, background service could be a better choice. and if you want get job status in time, we can use signalr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why did I come up with this background service idea?**

---

***Reason 1:*** The browser will have a limit of about 4 minutes.

[The request timed out. The web server failed to respond within the specified time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65212320/7687666).

If we call the long http running API in our UI page, the browser may crash.

***Reason 2:*** There are some third-party services, such as Azure Gateway and other related services that I am familiar with, have a 120s limit, and if the time is exceeded, [there will be 504 errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/http-response-codes#504--gateway-timeout). It same as your EC2.

---

**Solution**

1. Use [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio)
2. Use [ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

*Related links*

[Asp.Net core long running/background task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45015004/7687666)

[How to implement the more reliable approach](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html)